# UIButton in a UIView does not respond to user tapping when using Auto Layout (iOS)

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to create a grid like menu that can be shown if rightBarButton is being tapped.  It seems that the layout is correct (see pic below), but the cell (each of which is a UIButton) doesn't responds to user tapping.

[image: screenshot of the dropdown]

The dropdown (the part that is marked with red frame) is composed of two views.  One is GridCell and the other GridCollection. GridCell is simple a view containing a UIButton that occupies the whole of its container.  GridCollection init GridCells and positions them in order.

The following is the code extracted from GridCell

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color image:(UIImage *) cellImage title:(NSString *) title {
    self = [self init];
    if(self) {
        self.backgroundColor = color;
        self.image = cellImage;
        self.title = title;
        if(title == nil) self.title = @"default";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];
    [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    //button should fill container
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.cellButton = button;
    [self.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.cellButton setTitle:self.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.cellButton setTitle:@"pressed" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.cellButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.cellButton setBackgroundImage:self.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.cellButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.cellButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self addSubview:self.cellButton];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_cellButton]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_cellButton)]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_cellButton]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_cellButton)]];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:60]];
}

- (void)cellTapped {
    NSLog(@"cell %d pressed ", self.tag);
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"Printing button's frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.cellButton.frame));
}
```

The following is the code extracted from GridCollection

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];
    GridCell *previousCell = nil;
    GridCell *firstCell = nil;
    for (int i = 1; i <= self.numberOfCells; ++i) {
        GridCell *cell = [[[GridCell alloc] initWithColor:i % 2 == 0 ? [UIColor brownColor] : [UIColor grayColor] image:nil title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", i]] autorelease];
        cell.tag = i;
        [self addSubview:cell];
        [cell setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:self.superview.frame.size.width/4]];
        if (!previousCell) {  //pin to top left
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[cell]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell)]];
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[cell]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell)]];
            firstCell = cell;
        } else { //pin to previous
            if(i % 4 == 1 && i != 1) {
                [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[firstCell][cell]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"cell" : cell, @"firstCell" : firstCell}]];
                [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[cell]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell)]];
            } else {
                [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[previousCell]-0-[cell]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousCell, cell)]];
            }
        }
        previousCell = cell;
    }
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

For debugging purpose, I've put `NSLog(@"Printing button's frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.cellButton.frame))` in GridCell's layoutSubview method.  And I found that they all return 0,0 for button's origin. And I think perhaps this is the reason why my UIButton in the cell did not respond, is that right?

```
2014-08-04 21:36:42.837 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.838 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.839 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.840 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.840 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.841 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.842 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
2014-08-04 21:36:42.843 projectName[38661:60b] Printing button's frame: {{0, 0}, {80, 60}}
```

I am wondering how can I position cells' origin correctly in this occasion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After printing my view hierarchies, I found that it's because I did not assign height to my parent view gridview. Giving a height to that view solved this problem.

```
<GridView: 0x9b625a0; frame = (0 64; 320 0); tag = 100; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e4e720>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8e56db0; frame = (0 0; 80 60); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c680c0>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8ca6170; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8caea80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ca6260>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8ca3ae0; frame = (80 0; 80 60); tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ca47b0>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e57990; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e57a80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e57680>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8cae620; frame = (160 0; 80 60); tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ca7450>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e58490; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e585d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e58450>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8caf4d0; frame = (240 0; 80 60); tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c657d0>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e58fc0; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e59100>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e58f80>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8ca82e0; frame = (0 60; 80 60); tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0x8cb5450>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e59af0; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e59c30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e59ab0>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8caed70; frame = (80 60; 80 60); tag = 6; layer = <CALayer: 0x8caedf0>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e5a620; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e5a760>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e5a5e0>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8caf260; frame = (160 60; 80 60); tag = 7; layer = <CALayer: 0x8caf300>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e5b170; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e5b2b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e5b130>>
   |    <GridCell: 0x8cb0cc0; frame = (240 60; 80 60); tag = 8; layer = <CALayer: 0x8cb0d60>>
   |       | <UIButton: 0x8e5bca0; frame = (0 0; 80 60); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e5bde0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e5bc60>>
```

Answer (score 2):

That could be due by one of those problems:

1. The button is hosted outside the bounds of its superview. That also means if the superview has bounds {0,0}
2. you are loading cells from a xib, but the root view of these cells is not a UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am  doing it programmatically without xib.  Would tried to investigate in the direction of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into the reusable cell and not the button

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

also

```
_tableview.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I tried adding gesture recognizer to the cell. But the result is still the same.

Comment: cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES; ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to identify a grid of buttons is to assign different numbers to their tag properties.

myButton[0].tag = 0, mybutton[1].tag = 1; etc. Then look at the tag of the pressed button in the action method.

Comment: The button's selector "cellTapped" is not getting called so tag might not be very helpful here.